# Why does PCB copper surface oxidize when I apply flux on its surface?

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, flux

I had to create a printed circuit board for a project, using the home method (PCB developer solution, iron chloride.) At first, after the PCB was etched, I cleaned it very well using paper towels and isopropyl alcohol.

The PCB looked like this:

[image]

Then, I applied a thin layer of flux, hoping the soldering process will be better and the board will be protected a little. I used a flux dispensing pen because I didn't have any other kind of flux.

Here's the flux dispenser pen type I used:

[image]

Here's how the board looked after I applied the thin layer of flux:

[image]

I let it dry over night.

The next day, when I wanted to solder the components, I noticed that the soldering material wouldn't stick to copper, so I applied some more flux. Apparently, it worked, but some minutes later, the copper surface where I applied the flux turned green, with a dirty aspect:

[image]

Can someone help me with an answer, why did this happen? I assume it's the flux, but I'm not sure why.

Will the board be affected and in the end the traces will be destroyed?

Is there a solution to clean the dirt and protect the existing board?

Later edit:
I tried to fix the damage already done by cleaning the PCB with isopropyl alcohol as well as I could, and it turned out pretty well, in my opinion. Here's a photo of the cleaned PCB:

[image]

It's been over a month and the board works well, I had no problem with the connections. The project I used the PCB for is an UV exposure box. I've put the PCB inside a plastic case, and the plastic case is inside a bigger wood case, also protected with extruded polystyrene. I hope this way the PCB will be protected from humidity. Also, the humidity in the laboratory where the PCB is located is controlled, always under 40%.

Thank you for all your help and good advice, I learned a lot from your answers.

Comment: Incidentally, you don't need to remove the copper from where holes are going to be drilled through. That would stop the outline from becoming a bit thin if it get slightly over-etched. You could make a very small hole to help centre the drill bit.

Comment: The flux should be applied shortly before soldering. It should still be wet when you solder. Then a cleaner should be used afterward.

Comment: Flux is not a board treatment. You do not apply it in advance. You also do not apply it everywhere.

Comment: @DKNguyen I didn't know that. Some work colleagues taught me that and I took it for granted. I really appreciate the information you gave me, thank you!

Comment: Many thanks for your advice! @Justin

Comment: @VictoriaLi. If you want a solderable, corrosion-resistant finish, you could use PCB tin plating solution.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thank you for the advice, I will keep it in mind. Also I was thinking if applying soldering material on the traces could be a solution to protect them somehow (?), as I need to finish the project as soon as possible and don't have enough time to order/find somewhere the tin plating solution.

Comment: @VictoriaLi. it all depends. Is this an actual device that will actually be deployed somewhere and have to actually last? If so, then that wouldnt really be a great solution. However, it sounds like this is some school project, so in that case, yes its fine (even leaving the copper completely unprotected would have been basically fine as long as there was no chance of short circuits). If you really cared about the longevity, you would apply a conformal coating, but I can guarantee if this is for any sort of school project, you will be 100% fine for at least 6 months

Comment: unless they specifically ask you about longevity, in which case you would say: "well if this were actually going to be delpoyed in the field then I would have a soldermask and possibly a conformal coating" which I would almost guarantee would give you 100% marks. Billions of PCBs do not have any sort of conformal coating other than soldermask, and they last for decades (although as an engineer, you job is to assess the environment and make the appropriate choice, so if for example there was a corrosive atmosphere, you would add conformal coating)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at the [datasheet](https://www.chemtronics.com/content/msds/TDS_CW8300.pdf), you'll see a few important tips:

[image]

[image]

This flux must be cleaned after you apply it, since it is corrosive, and shouldn't be used on bits that you're not soldering. The latter is true for most (all?) fluxes.

The reason that water solubility is important for this flux is so that you can clean the PCB with water, and don't have to use other chemicals to clean it.

If you don't want to have to clean the flux, you could try [no-clean flux](https://www.newark.com/chemtronics/cw8100/flux-dispensing-pen-no-clean-9g/dp/00Z1870), which is less corrosive and doesn't absolutely need to be removed after soldering (although you still should remove it.) In order to remove this kind of flux, you will typically need chemicals (like isopropyl alcohol).

I'm not sure theres a way to fix the damage already done to the board, but you could try cleaning the corrosion off with [alcohol and scrubbing](https://gesrepair.com/clean-circuit-board/#clean-corrosion) and then protecting the board with some type of [conformal coating](https://www.tempoautomation.com/blog/what-pcb-coating-types-are-available-for-my-boards/).